# How do I get the significance in a test of population proportion?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

Usually on the internet and in books when testing for proportions they set H0 to be p=0.5 and H1 be p>0.5. What if I have
H0 : p<=0.5
H1 : p>0.5
How do I get the significance level for some critical set?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the same test in that the same one-sided critical values and p-values apply -- the main differences are (i) if the $<$ case is possible/being considered, then the type I error rate at the boundary should be the largest type I error rate (so if it's really "<" the actual type I error rate may be smaller than the nominal rate) - you use that worst case at the boundary, and (ii) in interpretation of a non-rejection (in the obvious way that the two nulls differ).